# Spring annotation for a global scope of function variables?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am working on a springboot+thymeleaf project. I have a page(form) which accepts user data (startdate and enddate),and a button(Check). On click of the button, backend does some validation. If there are errors, I print the errors on the textarea within the same page (below the check button). If there are no errors, then I activate another button below the textarea, to signify that the entries between the mentioned dates are ready to be stored in the database.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5">

<body>
    <div th:fragment="contentinput">
        <div class="container-md">
            <a>Import Worklogs</a>
            <div class="row justify-content-md-end">
                <form modelAttribute = "userData">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtFrom"
                                placeholder="start date(yyyy-mm-dd)" name="dateFrom">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtTo"
                                placeholder="end date(yyyy-mm-dd)" name="dateTo">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="row-2">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sml"
                                value="check">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div th:fragment="contentresult">
        <div class="container-md">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="row">
                    <label style="color: black; font-weight: bold;">Issues: </label>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="Feedback"
                        th:text="'checking entries between '+ ${dateFrom}+' and '+ ${dateTo}"></label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <textarea id="feedbackSection" name="story" cols="100" rows="10"
                        th:text="${styledErrors}">  
                        </textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label th:if="${containsErrors}" style="color: green;"> There are
                    no issues. The entries can be imported</label> 
                                
                <label
                    th:unless="${containsErrors}" style="color: red;"> There are
                    issues! Read the above for details</label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="row-2">
                    <a th:if="${containsErrors}" type="button" th:attr="href='/importToDb'" 
                        class="btn btn-primary btn-sml">Import</a> 
                    <input th:unless="${containsErrors}" type="button" disabled="disabled"
                        value="Import">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div th:fragment="contentmessage">
        <div class="container-md">
            <div class="row">
                <label style="color: green; font-weight: bold;"
                    th:text="'Entries between '+ ${dateFrom}+' and '+ ${dateTo}+' are stored on the database'"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have run into a problem in my controller application for the import button. When I click on the import, I want to utilise the features that were used while clicking the button (check)

```
 @GetMapping("/showform")
  public String showForm(@RequestParam(value = "dateFrom", required = false) String dateFrom,
      @RequestParam(value = "dateTo", required = false) String dateTo, Model model)
      throws IOException, JSONException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException,
      NumberFormatException, SQLException {
    if (dateFrom != null && dateTo != null && !dateFrom.isBlank() && !dateTo.isBlank()) {
      logger.info("inside the datefrom dateto");  
      CheckManager wm = prepareConfiguration(dateFrom, dateTo);
      model.addAttribute("containsErrors", wm.getErrors().isEmpty());
      model.addAttribute("styledErros", wm.getFormattedErrors(wm.getErrors()));
      model.addAttribute("dateFrom", dateFrom);
      model.addAttribute("dateTo", dateTo);
      return "showform-errors"; //shows the fragment with contentinput and contentResult
    } else {
      logger.info("inside the validationform");
      return "showform"; //only contentinput( having 2 textboxes for dates and a button)
    }
  }

  private CheckManager prepareConfiguration(String dateFrom, String dateTo)
      throws IOException, JSONException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException,
      NumberFormatException, SQLException {
    LocalDate from = LocalDate.parse(dateFrom, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    LocalDate to = LocalDate.parse(dateTo, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));


    Request req = new Request("username", "password");
    List<Entry> entrylist = req.getEntryList(from,to); 
    // I want this info entrylist to be used  globally

    return new CheckManager(entryList,from,to);
  }
  
  @GetMapping("/placeinDB")
  public String placeInDb(Model model) {
    logger.info("Inside the db import");
   //HERE I WOULD LIKE TO USE THE DATES AND THE LIST I HAD IN THE ABOVE RETURN STATEMENT
   }
```

Problem: When I hit the endpoint(/placeinDB) I do not have the resources like entryList, datefrom, dateTo to perform some modifications.
I am hoping there is some spring annotation that could help me here. Please let me know.

Comment: what is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: When I hit the endpoint (/placeinDB), I do not have the resources to playwith. I need the entryList , dates to write to DB

Comment: do you understand how scopes work in Java? Either you call that method from your placeInDB method, or you add that data in your model, or you don't have that data.

Comment: yeah, so point is, is there any way to add to the model in the global scope? Currently I am adding within another method

Comment: this is your code we are talking about. You should know all of that. Also, what do you mean: "global scope"?

Comment: I mean in a way, where it is accessible for all functions

Comment: a separate function,which would have all the details which I need while going hitting the endpoint(/placeinDB)

Comment: you already have a "separate method that has all the information", you need to call it, though. no, there isn't immediately a way to set this so it is available for all methods, since then you would create a statefull controller, which you shouldn't do. But, again: why don't you call that method from where you want that information?

Comment: That separate method you are referring to does a lot of validation already, and in the placeinDB, I do not want to repeat the whole procedure again. if I do it again, its just repeating the same functionalities and not optimal

Comment: You are referring to the method inside (/showForm) i beliebve

Comment: no I am not. and I don't see any validation in your placeinDB method, or in the method I am referring to. You stated that the information you need is in the method above placeinDB, which is not showForm, but prepareConfiguration

Comment: Alright, sorry for the gap. I mean  the showForm

Comment: in showForm you call prepareConfiguration. What is stopping you from doing the same from placeinDB? just make sure you have the right parameters to call it.

Comment: The workflow:  1) I enter the dates 2) Click on a button ( which hits the showForm endpoint). There is a lot of validation going on within. (Ofcourse not all are shown here). 3) If there are any errors, the errors are shown in the text area and the "import" button is disabled. 4) if there are no errors, then the "import" is active and onclick the entryList can be imported to DB

Comment: currently, If I create the same code again, repeating the validation again would occur.

Comment: ... no, it would not, unless you put it in there. Do you understand the concept of reusing common code?

Comment: why not just put a button to store in the database?
example, a 'save' button, which when clicked, the data will be validated, if everything is ok, the save is effective, else, it returns the errors to the page.